# where is internal storage, phone storage and external storage

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, internal-storage

Here is the files tree of my phone:

[image]

I've learnt that storage on Android OS is usually broken down into:

1. Internal storage (device built-in memory)
2. Phone storage (device built-in memory)
3. External storage (sd card)

I'm looking at the files tree and trying to figure out which is which :). I know that applications by default are installed into `/data/data` folder, so I assume that `/data/` folder counts as internal storage. There is also `/storage` folder which contains `sdcard0` and `sdcard1`. I've got only one sdcard on my phone - `sdcard1`. So maybe `sdcard0` is phone storage? Could it be that everything, which is outside `/storage` is considered internal storage?

Comment: android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've learnt that storage on Android OS is usually broken down into:

From the Android SDK's standpoint, those are [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), respectively.

> I know that applications by default are installed into /data/data folder, so I assume that /data/ folder counts as internal storage.

Your app's portion of internal storage will be on the `/data/` partition. Exactly where depends upon the account that is running your app (Android 4.2+ supports multiple accounts per device). The primary device account will have your app's portion of internal storage be at `/data/data/your.application.id.here/`.

> There is also /storage folder which contains sdcard0 and sdcard1. I've got only one sdcard on my phone - sdcard1. So maybe sdcard0 is phone storage?

By and large, that is up to the device manufacturer. Plus, each account gets its own location for external storage. And, to top it off, the answer varies depending on what you are using to examine the storage itself.

In DDMS' File Explorer, external storage for the primary device account will be at `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/`.

Comment: Thanks! Checked out your page at commonsware.com, can't find the option to buy your book?

Comment: @Maximus: Visit http://commonsware.com/Android/ and click the big blue "Subscribe" button, or visit http://commonsware.com/warescription to read more about the subscription program.

Comment: Got, thanks! I'll try to subscribe